# Powershell: I am creating my own module and struggling at managing external assemblies after I build with ModuleBuilder

Tags: c#, powershell, module, .net-assembly

I have a few powershell modules I've been working on for awhile and just recently started the process of packaging them with `Module Builder`. I've had no trouble with modules that don't have any external dependencies, but I'm stuck on one of my modules that reference some dll assemblies.

I have a `build.psd1` file pointing to my manifest and the `RequiredAssemblies` field in my manifest is filled out with the assembly names:

[image]

But when I build the module and then attempt to import it in a fresh shell, I get the following:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MahApps.Metro, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My DLL assemblies are located in a ./lib folder in my normal configuration. I've tried copying that folder to the output path using my `build.ps1` script (Where `Module Builder` places the final build), but it's still not finding the assemblies. I'm assuming this is because it doesn't look in the `lib` folder.

**How does one manage a PowerShell module with various external dependencies?**

I think I could just manually copy the DLL files to the root directory of the built module, but that's besides the point. This should be automated.

Is this something my `build.ps1` should be taking care of? Should I copy my .dll assemblies to the root of the built module via the `build.ps1`?

Any help at all would be vastly appreciated! I am completely stuck.

Edit: Providing my module structure to help facilitate an answer.

[image]

Here is my build script (build.ps1):

```
#requires -Module Configuration, @{ ModuleName = "ModuleBuilder"; ModuleVersion = "1.6.0" }

[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [ValidateSet("Release","Debug")]
    $Configuration = "Release",

    # The version of the output module
    [Alias("ModuleVersion","Version")]
    [string]$SemVer = '1.0.0'

)

Push-Location $PSScriptRoot -StackName BuildStack


try {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    Write-Host "## Calling Build-Module" -ForegroundColor Cyan

    $Module = Build-Module -Passthru -SemVer $SemVer
    $Folder = Split-Path $Module.Path

} catch {

    throw $_

} finally {


    $AssembliesToCopy = Get-ChildItem -Path "./Source/Lib" -Filter "*.dll"
    $AssembliesToCopy | ForEach-Object {
        $destinationFilePath = Join-Path -Path "../../VSYSModulesBuild/VSYSGUIOps" -ChildPath $_.Name
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destinationFilePath -Force
    }

    Pop-Location -StackName BuildStack

}
```

I got the module working by copying the dll's to the top level of the final directory in my build script above. I have no idea if this is best practice but it seems to work.

The only drawback is that my code warns (but doesn't fail):

```
Add-Type: Could not load file or assembly 'D:\Dev\Powershell\VSYSModulesBuild\Lib\Ookii.Dialogs.Winforms.dll'. 

The system cannot find the path specified.
```

This is because as I developed the module I pointed to ./lib to find assemblies. So it's complaining it can no longer find these dependencies. Fortunately the code still works because the assembly is already loaded at runtime.

I think I need to implement a check if an assembly is already loaded, and only attempt to load from ./lib if the assembly isn't loaded.

Sorry if this post is long and convoluted.

I could really use some experience from someone who has built modules with external dependencies before, and how they managed the process.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the folder structure of your module.

If you have assembly in the `lib` subfolder then it should be::

```
RequiredAssemblies = 'lib\MahApps.Metro.dll', ...
```

Comment: The problem is that when it gets packaged by `Module Builder`, the lib folder is no longer existent, so it still can't load the assembly anyway.

Comment: Just added a lot more information to the OP.